# Ability to flag each uploaded image separately after doing multiupload

Tags: nodes, ajax, flags

I want to create some kind of photography website where users will be able to flag some images for later use.

This is the user story:

1. Photographer upload images of the client event on the website
2. Page with a gallery is created
3. A client comes to the gallery page and marks few items using [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module
4. A view is created with a list of flagged images so Photographer can get a list of images for further manipulation

The problem is if I use multiple image field there is no way to use Flag module as it works only with nodes, and I have all images in a single node.

There is [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag/issues/1024536) in Flag module where it says why is not possible.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to convert images to nodes after creating an initial node that contains all of the images?

Or do you have any other suggestion how to handle this?

Comment: Does your question really have anything with ajax?

Comment: Well, i was under impression that some solution would work with Ajax, and now Ajax is also used for flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda went on another way, instead of doing this conversion I actually just used Media module which is now in the Core, and with that, I get every image as a single entity that is then able to be flagged.

So

- Use Media with [Entity Browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser) instead of regular Image Field
- Create view block and placed it in the content with contextual filters to take current ID from URL which then lists all images + flags
- Hide images on manage display in the content type so I don't get duplicates
- Create another View with flag relationship to list only flagged content

And that did the trick, I now have a gallery on a page where every image has a flag under it, and I'm able to export only flagged ones.

Answer (score 0):

It's easily possible to create a node per uploaded picture using a custom module. Alternatively, you could use https://www.drupal.org/project/node_gallery to let users upload every picture to its node from the very beginning.